# In term of starting a speech with the opposite opinion, does "good" in "good point" mean easy to attack, representative, or something else?

Tags: meaning

There is a video (https://youtu.be/UFuxlnUeGmg) talking about an easy tip to start an essay or speech.

> When you give your opinion, it's a very good idea to start by saying what is good about the opposite opinion.

At a time stamp (https://youtu.be/UFuxlnUeGmg?t=133), the video used a phrase "good point".

> it's always a good idea to start with the opposite of what you believe,
>   *a good point* of the opposite, and then to say your opinion. Okay?

Lots of people also use "good point" in their talking.

So, what is a "good point"?

## point

This [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21472/good-idea-vs-good-point) gives an explanation about *point*,

> A point is normally an argument to either support or attack an idea.

I am will to buy it.

## good

And then, what does "good" mean? I thought good means representative although I am not pretty sure.

Consider this example (https://youtu.be/UFuxlnUeGmg?t=92),

> Although some people love eating at home, I prefer eating at a restaurant.

She referred to "eating at home" as a *good point*.

By representative, I mean there might be more than one possibilities in the opposite of my intended opinion.

Consider the example of where to eat, there are more than one options in the opposite of eating at a restaurant, such as eating at home, eating at office, eating at street ...

So, what does "good" in "good point" mean? Does "good" in "good point" mean easy to attack, representative, or something else?

Comment: Fundamentally “good” means what your translation app or dictionary says it means (in your language!). You say you know what “point” means (having read the other post). So you need to explain to us why can’t you grasp what “good point” means?

Comment: _Good_ obviously has many meanings, but _a good point_ is an opinion that is perfectly valid and worth stating. If a family member is a good cook and enjoys cooking, it's perfectly sensible to say that you love eating (your main meal) at home.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Thanks for your reminder. I explained more just now.